# Dynamic XmlFile ElementPath property value in WIX?

Tags: wix

My project have 2 connectionstring for 2 database, connectionstrings name are "ABCDevelopment" and "XYZDevelopment"

I need to update dynamic connectionstring value for connection "ABCDevelopment" or "XYZDevelopment". But "MyProperty" is not work in ElementPath.

[image: Dynamic XmlFile ElementPath property value in WIX]

How can I do like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved using SetProperty

[image]